# problemas con getText de editText Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, edittext

Tengo un problema con dos `EditText` en particular, estos se encuentran en un `fragment`, la primera vez que llego al fragment, estos se encuentran vacios les asigno un número

```
( ej: et1 = 1, et2 = 2; )
```

realizo todas las operaciones de manera normal, dejo el `fragment` y lo reemplazo por otro, al volver al `fragment` con los `EditText` y les vuelvo a ingresar valores

```
( ej: et1 = 5, et2 = 6;)
```

estos al realizar un `et1.getText().toString();` me devuelve el valor 1 en vez del nuevo valor que es 5

¿que podría estar haciendo mal?

el valor de los `EditText` se asignan mediante usuario

Adjunto el codigo para un mejor entendimiento

```
public class ConfigPackingFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText cantidad_espesor, cantidad_ancho, bt;
    private ImageView chk1, chk2;
    private Button buton;
    private String code, RutCrea;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    private ArrayList<Double> arrayListEspesor = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Double> arrayListAncho = new ArrayList<>();
    private int contadorEspesor = 0, contadorAncho = 0,ID_UPDATE = 0,dispo;


//    BLUETOOTH

    private BluetoothDevice[] btArray;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

    View view;

    private int REGUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH=1;

    private static final String APP_NAME = "BTchat";
    private static final UUID MY_UUID=UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // String for MAC address
    private static String address = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;



    final int handlerState = 0;
    private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista_datos, container, false);
        bindUI();

        cantidad_espesor.requestFocus();


            /*cantidad_ancho.setText(null);
            cantidad_espesor.setText(null);
            cantidad_espesor.getText().clear();
            cantidad_ancho.getText().clear();*/

        SharedPreferences prefs = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences("config_tel", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        code = prefs.getString("codigo_busqueda", "");
        ID_UPDATE = prefs.getInt("id_update", 0);
        dispo = prefs.getInt("id_dispo", 0);
        RutCrea = prefs.getString("rut_user", "");

        bt.setText("");

        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        Objects.requireNonNull(activity.getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Class nuevoFragmento = DetailFragment.class;
                cambiarFragment(nuevoFragmento);
            }
        });

        buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                comenzarCiclo();
            }
        });

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REGUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
            }
            if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                pairedDevice();
            }
        }



        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_config_packing, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.btn_list_bt:
                Class nuevoFragmento = ListaBT.class;
                cambiarFragment(nuevoFragmento);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }


    public void cambiarFragment( Class fragmentClass){
        Fragment fragment = null;
        try {
            fragment = (android.support.v4.app.Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.detailsContainer, fragment)/*.addToBackStack(null)*/.commit();
//        .addToBackStack(null)
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == handlerState) {          //if message is what we want
                String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                                                                // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
//                recDataString.append(readMessage);              //keep appending to string until ~
//                int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~");                    // determine the end-of-line
//                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // make sure there data before ~
//                    String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);    // extract string
                    bt.setText(readMessage);
                    if (bt.getText().length() > 0){
                        asignarMedidas();
                    }


//                    int dataLength = dataInPrint.length();       //get length of data received
//                    txtStringLength.setText("Tamaño del String = " + String.valueOf(dataLength));

                   /* if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '#')        //if it starts with # we know it is what we are looking for
                    {
                        String sensor0 = recDataString.substring(1, 5);             //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5
                        String sensor1 = recDataString.substring(6, 10);            //same again...
                        String sensor2 = recDataString.substring(11, 15);
                        String sensor3 = recDataString.substring(16, 20);

                        if(sensor0.equals("1.00"))
                            sensorView0.setText("Encendido"); //update the textviews with sensor values
                        else
                            sensorView0.setText("Apagado"); //update the textviews with sensor values
                        sensorView1.setText(sensor1);
                        sensorView2.setText(sensor2);
                        sensorView3.setText(sensor3);
                        //sensorView3.setText(" Sensor 3 Voltage = " + sensor3 + "V");
                    }*/
//                    recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());      //clear all string data
                    // strIncom =" ";
//                    dataInPrint = " ";
//                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        destruirTodo();

        if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
            if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                pairedDevice();
            }
        }
    }


    public void destruirTodo(){
        contadorAncho = 0;
        contadorEspesor = 0;
        arrayListEspesor = null;
        arrayListAncho = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        destruirTodo();
}

    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

        return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        //creates secure outgoing connecetion with BT device using UUID
    }

    private void pairedDevice(){
        // Add previosuly paired devices to the array
        SharedPreferences prefs = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences("config_tel", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String addrs = prefs.getString("mac", "");

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(addrs)) {
            BluetoothDevice devices = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(addrs);
            try {
                btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(devices);
                Toasty.success(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), "Conectado a " + devices.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG, true).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toasty.error(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), "La creacción del Socket fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG, true).show();
            }
            // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
            try {
                btSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    btSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    //insert code to deal with this
                }
            }
            mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
            mConnectedThread.start();
        }
            //I send a character when resuming.beginning transmission to check device is connected
            //If it is not an exception will be thrown in the write method and finish() will be called
//                    mConnectedThread.write("x");

    }


    //create new class for connect thread
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        //creation of the connect thread
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                //Create I/O streams for connection
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }


        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;

            // Keep looping to listen for received messages
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            //read bytes from input buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                    handler.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //write method
/*        public void write(String input) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();           //converts entered String into bytes
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);                //write bytes over BT connection via outstream
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //if you cannot write, close the application
                Toasty.error(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), "La Conexión fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG,true).show();
//                Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).finish();

            }
        }*/
    }

    private void asignarMedidas(){
        int maxEspesor, maxAncho;
        System.out.println(cantidad_ancho.getText().toString() + "__"+ cantidad_espesor.getText().toString());
        if(cantidad_espesor.getText().length() <= 0 || cantidad_ancho.getText().length() <= 0) {
            Toast.makeText(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), "Debe ingresar ambos valores antes de comenzar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else
            {
                if (contadorEspesor == 0){ arrayListEspesor = new ArrayList<>(); }
                if (contadorAncho == 0){ arrayListAncho = new ArrayList<>(); }
            try {
                Double numeroBT = Double.parseDouble(bt.getText().toString());

                maxAncho = Integer.parseInt(cantidad_ancho.getText().toString());
                maxEspesor = Integer.parseInt(cantidad_espesor.getText().toString());


                System.out.println("NUMERO MAXIMO ESPESOR " + Integer.parseInt(cantidad_ancho.getText().toString()));
                System.out.println("NUMERO MAXIMO ANCHO " + Integer.parseInt(cantidad_espesor.getText().toString()));

                contadorEspesor++;
                //mientras el contador de espesor (que es el primero) sea menor o igual al espesor este sumará +1 y se agregará un nuevo valor a el array de espesor
                if (contadorEspesor <= maxEspesor) {
                    arrayListEspesor.add(numeroBT);
                }
                //cuando el contador de espesor sea mayor o igual
                if (contadorEspesor > maxEspesor) {
                    contadorAncho++;
                    chk1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (contadorAncho <= maxAncho) {
                        arrayListAncho.add(numeroBT);
                    }
                }
                if (arrayListEspesor.size() == maxEspesor && arrayListAncho.size() == maxAncho) {
                    chk2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    final Paquete paquete = new Paquete();
                    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            final List<Paquete> pqt = InfoPacking.myAppDB.myDao().getPaquete(code);
                            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    if (pqt.size() > 0) {
                                        for (Paquete pqte : pqt) {
                                            paquete.setEtiqueta(pqte.getEtiqueta());
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                                        paquete.setEtiqueta(timeStamp);
                                    }

                                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
                                    Date da = new Date();
                                    String fechaFinal = df.format(da);

                                    paquete.setEspesor(arrayListEspesor);
                                    paquete.setAncho(arrayListAncho);

                                    List<Paquete> getPack = InfoPacking.myAppDB.myDao().getPaqueteById(ID_UPDATE);
                                    for (Paquete paquete1 : getPack) {
                                        paquete.setEtiqueta(paquete1.getEtiqueta());
                                        paquete.setHumedad(paquete1.getHumedad());
                                        paquete.setDetFam(paquete1.getDetFam());
                                        paquete.setLargo(paquete1.getLargo());
                                        paquete.setDescProd(paquete1.getDescProd());
                                        paquete.setIdPaquete(paquete1.getIdPaquete());
                                        paquete.setFecha(paquete1.getFecha());
                                        paquete.setNombProd(paquete1.getNombProd());
                                        paquete.setObservacion(paquete1.getObservacion());
                                        paquete.setDispo(dispo);
                                        paquete.setRutCrea(RutCrea);
                                        paquete.setFechaDisp(fechaFinal);
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        int numero = InfoPacking.myAppDB.myDao().updatePaquetes(paquete);

                                        if (numero > 0) {
                                            showAlertForObservaciones("Todo Bien", "Todos los datos se han guardado en el telefono correctamente", code, ID_UPDATE);
                                        }
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.getMessage();
                                        e.getStackTrace();
                                        System.out.println("ERROR DE LA BD" + e);
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No se insertaron las medidas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    Toasty.success(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), " TOMA FINALIZADA CON EXITO ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Toasty.error(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), "error de datos, debe ser un numero decimal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void showAlertForObservaciones(String title, String message, final String codigo, final int id_paquete ) {
        View viewInfalted = LayoutInflater.from(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).inflate(R.layout.alert_empty, null);

        final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()))
                .setView(viewInfalted)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("cancelar",null).create();

        builder.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Button b = builder.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Bundle bndl = new Bundle();
                        bndl.putString("codigo", codigo);
                        bndl.putInt("idPaquete", id_paquete);
                        Fragment nuevoFragmento = new ObservacionesFragment();
                        assert getFragmentManager() != null;
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        nuevoFragmento.setArguments(bndl);
                        transaction.replace(R.id.detailsContainer, nuevoFragmento);
//                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                        builder.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.show();
    }
    private void comenzarCiclo() {
        cantidad_espesor.setEnabled(false);
        cantidad_ancho.setEnabled(false);
    }


    private void bindUI(/*View view*/){
        buton= view.findViewById(R.id.button_datos);
        bt= view.findViewById(R.id.bt);
        cantidad_ancho = view.findViewById(R.id.et_diametro_cant);
        cantidad_espesor = view.findViewById(R.id.et_espesor_cant);
        chk1 = view.findViewById(R.id.chk_espesor);
        chk2 = view.findViewById(R.id.chk_ancho);
        toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        RecyclerView listaMedidas = view.findViewById(R.id.lista_medidas);
    }

}
```

al recibir un valor mediante bluethooth se activa una funcion,en esta funcion llamo a los edittext antes llenados por el usuario

```
maxAncho = Integer.parseInt(cantidad_ancho.getText().toString());
maxEspesor = Integer.parseInt(cantidad_espesor.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Les asignas un numero mediante setText() ?, te sugiero agregar tu código sebastian.

Comment: se asigna mediante usuario, adjunte el codigo del fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pude dar con el problema, adjunto codigo especifico que cambié

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        destruirTodo();
        if(bluetoothAdapter != null){
            if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                if (btSocket != null){
                    if (btSocket.isConnected()){
                        try{
                            btSocket.close();
                        }catch (IOException e){
                            e.getLocalizedMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

con esto, al momento de dejar el fragment, cerraba la el socket utilizado, al momento de volver al fragment hago en onResume()

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        destruirTodo();

        if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                int REGUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;
                startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REGUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
                new AsyntaskPairedDevice().execute();
//                pairedDevice();
            }/*else{
//                new AsyntaskPairedDevice().execute();
                pairedDevice();
            } */
        }
    }

public class AsyntaskPairedDevice extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Toast.makeText(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), "Emparejando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return pairedDevice();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            if (aBoolean){
                ConnectedThread mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
                mConnectedThread.start();
                Toast.makeText(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), "Emparejado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

así al volver al fragment, vuelvo a enlazar con el disp bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

```
la verdad nunca he utilizado bluethoo pero puede que estes llamndolos mas intenta de la siguiente manera:
```

cantidad1_espesor.setText(Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString()));
cantidad1_ancho.setText(Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString()));

nota: no se si es lo que realmente buscas

Comment: No, no es lo que buscaba, peo solucione el problema que tenia, pasaba que al momento de pausar (onPause()) el fragment, no limpiaba la conexión po bluetooth, entonces al momento de volver al fragment, esta (la conexión bt) aun conservaba los parametros de antes.